# How do I include Unity Cardboard into an existing app?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I went through the Unity Google Cardboard example and I am unsure how to do 2 things with it. I want to add the player that gets built from Unity to an existing app, and I want to be able to swap the scene that gets played from the parent app. How would I go about this?

Comment: Can you explain more specifically? I don't understand your question.

Comment: When you use the Unity SDK to create a cardboard app, it creates a full project. I just want to include cardboard inside of my existing app. Is there anyway to do that?